# How to shoot particle like projectile?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I made a tank that shoot sphere balls on mouse click.

my C# script:

```
 GameObject prefab;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     prefab = Resources.Load("projectile") as GameObject;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update() {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     {
         GameObject projectile = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
         projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
         Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 40;
     }   

 }
```

in this script im shooting a mesh named `projectile`. But I want to shoot a particle ball and not a mesh. I already tried to change the `particle` to `Orbparticle` on script but no object was spawned. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No object was spawned because you probably don't have a resource called `Orbparticle`. Check if you have any errors when you run your script. If [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) doesn't find the object you want by the path you gave it, it will give `null`, which probably why no object is being spawned.

If you want to shoot a particle instead of a mesh then what you need to do is set `prefab` to a GameObject you prepared ahead of time that has the ParticleSystem you want. I'd suggest against using Resources.Load for this.

## 1. Using Resources.Load.

Change your code to this so that it will alert you if it doesn't find the resource:

```
GameObject prefab;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    string name = "OrbParticle";
    prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(name);
    if (prefab == null) {
        Debug.Error("Resource with name " + name + " could not be found!");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
        projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
        Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 40;
    }   
}
```

Now in order for this to work you need a prefab called "OrbParticle" or whatever string you set the variable `name` to. Resources.Load looks for items in paths such as `Assets/Resources`. So you MUST have your "OrbParticle" prefab located in that Resources folder. Unless you have a specific reason for using Resources.Load, I strongly suggest you go with solution 2.

## 2. Ditching Resources.Load and using the Prefab directly.

Change your code to this:

```
public GameObject prefab;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
        projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
        Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 40;
    }   
}
```

Then do this:

1. Create a new empty GameObject.
2. Attach a ParticleSystem to the GameObject.
3. Make a new prefab asset.
4. Drag and drop the newly created GameObject into a Prefab asset.
5. Drag and drop the the prefab into `prefab` field in your Monobehaviour (the object doing the shooting. It will have a prefab field in the Inspector. That's why we set `prefab` to be a public field).

---

If you continue having problems, look in Unity's Hierarchy to see if no object is being created at all. It might be the case that it is instantiating a GameObject but the GameObject is invisible for some reason or not instantiating in the location you expect.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but your method 2 is also prone to error, as the projectile might not have a rigidbody, you can add a null check before `rb.velocity =...` to prevent a possible null error, or you can remove this requirement altogether if you make the `prefab` a Rigidbody instead of a GameObject, and instantiate it using `Instantiate(prefab.gameObject)`  still a pretty solid answer though.

Comment: @Eddge That is a good practice, but I didn't add that check because I didn't think it was relevant to the question. I considered whether the projectile could be invisible simply because it didn't have a rigidbody and got stuck at the camera's origin as a result of being unable to set its velocity. But then I noticed that they specifically set the spawn point 2 units ahead of camera's forward vector so it's very likely the object would be visibly stuck. I suppose having good quality code is always relevant though. Overall, we need Unity's console log from SHRIMP.

Comment: Indeed, but I only pointed out the RB as another possibility of being a null error, because it could have aborted out of that function due to a null error, I had a spawn method do that once.  As you stated though, having the console log would be immensely helpful